# compilation error with throwing exception

Tags: java, compilation, throws

```
public class A {
    public void f(A a) {
        System.out.print("in A ");
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A();
        b.f(b);
        b.f(a);
    }
}
```

Why by adding the following method in B class there will be a compilation error?

It's known that if method throws something, it doesn't have to be declared in the method header...

```
public void f(A a) { 
    System.out.println("in B"); 
    throw new java.io.IOExeption();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's known that if method throws something, it doesn't have to be declared in the method header

That's only true for unchecked exceptions. Your method throws an `IOException` which is a *checked exception* so you must either catch it or declare that you throw it otherwise compilation will fail.

Comment: **unchecked exceptions** never have to be declared in the method header? and is it the only reason for compiler error in the given example?

Comment: No, they don't have to be declared in the method header, and you are not obligated to surround them with try/catch. I don't see anything else that might fail compilation in your code.